# jQuery Step Slider Outputting Multiple Variables (Prices)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I have a slider that needs to move through a set of points equal distant from one another, while displaying completely arbitrary pricing.

For example, I've got 4 server configurations that need to move the monthly rate to 50, 100, 201 and 403 dollars.  The Rackspace and Amazon prices also need to update to show completely different numbers... 86, 245, 648, and 864 for Rackspace and 43, 86, 172, and 345 dollars.  Meaning that when the server shows $50, Rackspace will show $86 and Amazon will show $86.  This is probably jQuery 101 or something. lol

Out of the box, the slider only gives me the values of the coordinates.

My jQuery knowledge is a bit poor, while I can read what's going on, and I know what I want it to do, I just can't figure out how translate that into writing.

```
$(function() {
$( "#slider" ).slider({
    value: 0,
    min: 50,
    max: 498,
    stepValues: [50, 114, 178, 243, 306, 370, 434, 498],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {

        var stepValues = $(this).slider("option", "stepValues"),

            distance = [],
            minDistance = $(this).slider("option", "max"),
            minI;

            $.each(stepValues, function(i, val) {
                distance[i] = Math.abs( ui.value - val );
                    if ( distance[i] < minDistance ) {
                        minDistance = distance[i];
                        minI = i;
                    }
            });

            if ( minDistance ) {
                $(this).slider("value", stepValues[ minI ]);
                return false;
            }

        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
    }
});
$( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );

});
```

Here's a semi half-working version of the step slider on my project: http://robsdesign.com/nebo/internap/cloud.html

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

There is some javascript missing. As you can see, whenever you hover the mouse over the slider, it is added a ui-hover class, and when you click down on it, you get a ui-active class. This is probably triggered or trigger an event which updates the slider position. You could do 2 things. Listen for this event and update the values, or place the code in the same code that updates the slider.

You need this line for the estimated monthly cost:

```
$( "#amount" ).val( *here); // place *here the value you want to update
```

and you need to add ids to the html that contains the other two price values:

```
<span class="cost">$263/Month</span>
```

and

```
<span class="cost">$238/Month</span>
```

to something like :

```
<span class="cost" id="rack">$263/Month</span>
```

and

```
<span class="cost" id="amazon">$238/Month</span>
```

and then update their values with these lines.

```
$( "#rack" ).val( *here); // place *here the value you want to update
```

and

```
$( "#amazon" ).val( *here); // place *here the value you want to update
```

The value on which you would be basing your update would be the style "left" that your slider gets when you change its position:

for example, in the first position, you have 0%

```
<a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 0%;"></a>
```

and for the next position you get this value:

```
<a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 14.285714285714285%;"></a>
```